# Localised currency Email Recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, einstein-recommendations

I'm facing some difficulties around the email recommendations and especially to make them localised. I need to show a different currency for Denmark (kr) then the currency for France (€). I have the following fields in my catalog to work with localised currencies: locale_nl-NL_CurrencySymbol|locale_fr-FR_CurrencySymbol|locale_da-DK_CurrencySymbol. The mapping of CurrencySymbol has been made and I the catalog doesn't show any errors.

I have the following code included in my Display:

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%[ if CurrencySymbol == "kr" then ]%%
%%SalePriceMain%%.%%RegularPriceFractional%% kr
%%[ else ]%%
€%%SalePriceMain%%.%%RegularPriceFractional%%
%%[ endif ]%%
</div>
```

The url of the recommendations looks like:

```
<a href="https://510004158.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/61263a01937639003941f3f7/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?%%Locale%%">
    <img src="https://510004158.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/61263a01937639003941f3f7/i/1/%%emailaddr%%?%%Locale%%">
```

It seems like that the IF from my display is not being recognised.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your "CurrencySymbol" is not a variable to be compared to the "kr" value. It seems that you need to set it with some value and then use it in the comparison. Can you try it out?

Comment: Hi @Niko, thanks for the quick reply. In my catalog the column locale_da-DK_CurrencySymbol has a value with kr. Do you think I need to target that specifically?

Comment: Hello, yes, try to target it, and let's say set it to `@CurrencySymbol` variable, which should be used later on in the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Locale fields incorrectly

You should create a catalog field like RegPrice_Display and localize this with each language you want an image created for

In your catalog you would have 
locale_nl-NL_RegPrice_Display  € 69.99
locale_fr-FR_RegPrice_Display  € 69.99
locale_da-DK_RegPrice_Display  kr 69.99

Then in your display, you would simply have

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%RegPrice_Display%%
</div>
```

Your [localized recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5) also should be corrected with the parameter locale=:

`<a href="https://XXXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/XXXXXXXXXXX/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?locale=%%Locale%%">`
`<img src="https://XXXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/XXXXXXXXXX/i/1/%%emailaddr%%??locale=%%Locale%%`

When you pass a locale field the system returns a different image (it builds one image for each locale)

Similar to below

`https://euw1-pi-templates.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/production/XXXXXX/1234~1_da-dk.png`

vs. NON-localized:

`https://euw1-pi-templates.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/production/XXXXXX/1234~1.png`

Comment: Thanks! This resolved the issue